# Convert Day of the Year in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, date

How can I convert Day of the Year to a mm/dd format in Excel?

Date of the Year: e.g. 1= Jan 1, 177 = June 27.

For example, how do I convert "177" to 6/27?

Comment: 177 is not June 27; it is June 25 in leap year (31+29+31+30+31+25=177) and June 26 otherwise (31+28+31+30+31+26=177).

Answer (score 2):

Add `41274` to it `=A1+41274` and then

`Right click - Format Cells - custom` and type in `mmm dd` or `mmmm dd` if you want the month name.

This will work for year 2013 because Jan 01, 2013 is 41,274 days after Jan 01, 1900

Comment: You'll need to add the offset from 1/1/1900 to the year required (41274 days for 2013) as it's different for leap years

Answer (score 0):

For numbers greater than 59 (31+28), the answer is different for leap year and non-leap year. 
To get the answers for the current year, put

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, A1)
```

in a helper column and format as you wish.  To use some other year, use

> `=DATE(`*yyyy*`, 1, A1)`